# What's another way of saying "closed the laptop"?

Tags: word-choice

**So I want to say "I angrily closed the laptop." Like this:**
[image]

Instead of using the quote above, what else can I say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An informal sentence could be:

*"I slammed the laptop shut".*

Comment: Thank you for such an awesome answer.This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note you can also close the *lid* of the laptop if you like.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

**Clamshelled** works for laptops and the like. The verb forms don't seem to have made it to the dictionaries yet, but [they're all over the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=clamshelled%20laptop&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

> Clamshelling his laptop, hard, Doug turned and scowled at Patti.

Comment: I'm familiar with "clamshell' as a description of the design, but how commonly is it used as a verb? As a verb wouldn't it apply equally to *opening* the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "shut the laptop". If you like, qualify it with some adjective.

Answer (score 0):

The animated gif you'd shown does not show ***anger***, IMO.

I would say, instead:

> He *indignantly* closed the laptop.

---

Indignance is a **more controlled** form of angry-feelings.

Comment: "Indigence"? I think you mean "indignation".

Comment: yea pardon, was meant to be indignance.  Pity; the OP's gif does not involve slamming.   It's very controlled and deliberate

Answer (score -3):

I would say "He Shuttered his laptop"

Comment: "Shuttered" means something very different to "shut".

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Unfortunately, your post has been flagged as poor quality and has garnered some down votes. High quality answers often contain a link to a dictionary entry.